# Why is there a phasor in the transfer function of an ideal LPF?

Tags: frequency-spectrum, lowpass-filter, transfer-function

I'm learning about Low Pass Filters. My professor said the following is the transfer function of an ideal LPF:

$$H_{LPF}(f) = G\Pi\left(\frac{f}{2B_{pass}}\right) e^{-j2\pi ft_0}$$

However, i don't understand why a phasor is needed. Wouldn't the fact that the LPF is centered around the DC component remove the need for a phasor?

Comment: That's an odd definition. What exactly are $G$ and $\Pi$ supposed to be?

Comment: @Hilmar $G$ is just the gain and $\Pi$ is the boxcar function (ideal low pass filter).

Answer (score 4):

The phasor in this case is the Fourier Transform of a time delay $t_o$, which is a negative linear phase in frequency as $e^{-j2\pi f t_o}$. This would represent the time delay of the filter between the input and output as $t_o$ seconds.

The reason it may be "needed" is in the process of implementing a realizable causal filter where a truncation in the time domain would also be required; we start with an ideal lowpass filter without any time delay which would have an impulse response as a Sinc Function in the time domain centered on $t=0$:

[image: Ideal Lowpass Filter]

The problem with the impulse response toward realizability is that it is non-causal (has components where $t<0$) and extends to positive and negative infinity. To realize the filter, we add a time delay $t_o$ which results in a negative linear phase in the frequency domain as shown below (and given by the Fourier Transform of $x(t+t_o)$ which is $e^{-j2\pi f t_o}$), and truncate the response to make it causal (the dashed line below shows multiplying the time response with a rectangular window, but other windows can be used to improve the frequency response):

[image: Ideal Lowpass Filter with Time Delay]

The realizable filter will no longer be the ideal rectangular response in the frequency domain after multiplying with a rectangular window in the time domain (which means convolving with another Sinc function in the frequency domain), resulting in the realized lowpass filter response as depicted below:

[image: Realized Lowpass Filter]